# Deleting a named excel range if it exists. Doing nothing if it doesn't

Tags: excel

Sorry I have tried looking for a few answers and have not found it here or on MrExcel yet. 
I just want a macro to go to a sheet, lets call the sheet data
And if there is a named range there, I want to delete the name.

The name of the range will best Test.

If it is not there, it doesn't matter, nothing at all needs to happen.

Sorry if it has been answered, but I have not had any of the ones I tried work.

Comment: Sorry can this be deleted?
I got another answer person just respond to me and they have provided something that is working. 

Please delete

Comment: Try this. Turn on macro recording. Do the procedure manually. Stop recording. Adjust the generated macro.

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/44907-list-out-named-ranges-vba.html https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1550-excel-delete-all-named-ranges.html#a2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For Each Nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
 Nm.Delete
```

This plus the links I have given in the comment above the question should suffice.